# XmlReader stops deserializing after first array property

Tags: c#, xml

I have a custom list used to have features of `BindingList<T>` while also being XML serializable. The `SBindingList<T>` class is as follows:

```cs
public class SBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.Read();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        List<T> ts = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        foreach (T item in ts)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this.ToList());
    }
}
```

The idea is to read and write the XML as if it was a `List<T>` behind the scenes but still works and acts like a `BindingList<T>`. The issue I'm having is that it starts reading `<Games>` then when it gets to `Add(item);` starts to deserialize `<AvailableQuests>`. Because `<AvailableQuests>` is empty it just falls out of `ReadXml` but goes immediately back finishing up adding `<Games>` and just falls out of `ReadXml` without even touching `<Characters>` or `<ActiveQuests>`. The `<Games>`, `<AvailableQuests>`, `<Characters>`, and `<ActiveQuests>` are all `SBindingList<T>`s. Also note that I redacted all the IDs for privacy reasons. Just replace the `[blah]` tags with any `ulong`.

```
<Games>
    <ArrayOfGame xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Game GuildID="[GuildID]" BotChannel="0" QuestChannel="0">
            <AvailableQuests>
                <ArrayOfQuest />
            </AvailableQuests>
            <Characters>
                <ArrayOfCharacter>
                    <Character Name="The Real Dirty Dan" Class="Meme" Level="17"
                        OwnerID="[Owner1]" Busy="false" />
                    <Character Name="Bob" Class="Builder" Level="2" OwnerID="[Owner2]"
                        Busy="false" />
                </ArrayOfCharacter>
            </Characters>
            <ActiveQuests>
                <ArrayOfQuest />
            </ActiveQuests>
        </Game>
    </ArrayOfGame>
</Games>
```

Here is the object setup incase someone needs it:

```cs
public class Game
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Only for serialization
    /// </summary>
    public Game() { }

    public Game(ulong guildID)
    {
        GuildID = guildID;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What discord server is the game on
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute]
    public ulong GuildID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public ulong BotChannel { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public ulong QuestChannel { get; set; }

    public SBindingList<Quest> AvailableQuests { get; set; } = new SBindingList<Quest>();

    public SBindingList<Character> Characters { get; set; } = new SBindingList<Character>();

    public SBindingList<Quest> ActiveQuests { get; set; } = new SBindingList<Quest>();

    public string Test { get; set; } // This gets ignored too

    public Character GetCharacterByName(string name)
    {
        return (from c in Characters
                where c.Name == name
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I don't really know where to start with this one. I've tried using a `List<T>` or just reading each `T` one at a time but both ways end up ignoring all other elements. My only guess is that I need to clean something up with the `reader` before I can let it fall out of `ReadXml` like `reader.FinishedReading()`.

Comment: A list is not an array. Did you try with `Character[]` ?

Comment: @rene Check `SBindingList<T>.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)` That is the way that `List<T>` is serialized, unless I'm misunderstanding your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this lies in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml?view=net-6.0#remarks) for `ReadXml`:

> When this method is called, the reader is positioned on the start tag that wraps the information for your type. That is, directly on the start tag that indicates the beginning of a serialized object. When this method returns, it must have read the entire element from beginning to end, including all of its contents. Unlike the `WriteXml` method, the framework does not handle the wrapper element automatically.

You seem to have spotted this by calling `reader.Read()` at the start (to move past the start tag and onto the content), but you haven't at the end. The fix is to call `reader.Read()` again afterwards.

Perhaps a better approach would be to call `reader.ReadStartElement()` first and `reader.ReadEndElement()` at the end. This just calls `reader.Read()` internally, but it will throw an exception in the case the reader isn't in the expected state.

I'd also suggest sharing a static serialiser instance rather than creating a new one each time you read or write a list. So this should work:

```cs
public class SBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, IXmlSerializable
{
    private static readonly XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();

        var items = (List<T>)Serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(writer, this.ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reader needs to be at the next element (in this case `<Characters>`) in the original object otherwise it just returns if it is at a end element node. This solution isn't failproof or the cleanest but it gets the job done. If I find something better that confirms that it is at the next elemet before falling out I will edit this answer.

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.Read();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    XmlReader xmlReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
    xmlReader.Read();
    List<T> ts = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    foreach (T item in ts)
    {
        Add(item);
    }
    xmlReader.Close();
    reader.Skip();
    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

The key is `reader.Skip()` and `reader.ReadEndElement()` lines. The `Skip()` function moves the reader to `</AvailableQuests>` and the `ReadEndElement()` makes sure that it is an end element (Like it needs to be) and moves to `<Characters>`.

Edit: use https://stackoverflow.com/a/71969803/4771954

Edit 2: After some trouble with this class again, I connected the dots to a section in `BindingList<T>` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-componentmodel-bindinglist-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ilist((-0))):%7E:text=Use%20this%20BindingList%3CT%3E%20to%20create%20a%20BindingList%3CT%3E%20that%20is%20backed%20by%20list%2C%20which%20ensures%20that%20changes%20to%20list%20are%20reflected%20in%20the%20BindingList%3CT%3E.) and found a branching alternate solution. The idea is to have 3 new properties as follows and a line added to all constructors:

```
public Game()
{
    Characters = new BindingList<Character>(CharacterList);
}

[XmlElement("Characters")]
public Character[] CharacterArray 
{
    get => CharacterList.ToArray();
    set
    {
        CharacterList.Clear();
        CharacterList.AddRange(value);
        Characters.ResetBindings();
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public List<Character> CharacterList { get; private set; } = new List<Character>();

[XmlIgnore]
public BindingList<Character> Characters { get; private set; }
```

If the `BindingList<T>` was initialized using a `List<T>`, the `BindingList<T>` would use that `List<T>` to store all the object data within itself. The line in the constructor of `BindingList<T>` is similar to `internalList = list;`. This allows the list given to the `BindingList<T>(IList list)` constructor to be edited, but won't notify subscribers of the change. Not only does this avoid having to make a new `BindingList<T>` type but allows all the `List<T>` features to be used like `CharacterList.Sort()` as long as all the modifications are followed up by a `Characters.ResetBindings()` to let subscribers know that the list has changed.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Games));
            Games games = (Games)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class Games
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ArrayOfGame")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Game")]
        public List<Game> game { get; set; }
 
    }
    public class Game
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string GuildID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int BotChannel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int QuestChannel { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "AvailableQuests")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ArrayOfQuest")]
        public List<Quest> availableQuest { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Characters")]
        public Characters characters { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ActiveQuests")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ArrayOfQuest")]
        public List<Quest> activeQuest { get; set; }
        public class Quest
    {
    }
    public class Characters
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ArrayOfCharacter")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Character")]
        public List<Character> character { get; set; }
    }
    public class Character
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Class { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int Level { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public Boolean Busy{ get; set; }
    }
    public class ArrayOfQuest
    {
    }

}}
```

Comment: This is just paste object from XML and doesn't fix the issue. To remind you, I'm having issues with the custom serialization because I need to serialize a `BindingList<T>` but when deserializing `Games` it only deserializes `<AvailableQuests>` then moves on.

Comment: Your classes are wrong!  First get working with my classes.  You can then change the type to 'T'.  If you notice the List<Game> object is wrapped with two tags Games, and ArrayOfGame.

Comment: I don't understand why my classes are wrong because in my custom serializer, I serialize it as a list and it should get deserialized as a list. Please explain to me how this leads into creating a custom serialization method? Why does having a custom deserializer cause only the first non-attribute be read then give up reading the rest without an error?

Comment: My code is tested and works.  Your code does not work.  XML Serializer will give only one result when an array is not specified without errors.  Compare my classes to your to see the differences.

Comment: This 'works' because it ignores the requirement to serialise a `BindingList<T>`. The only issue with the current code is the implementation of `IXmlSerializable` within that custom list.

Comment: Start with working code and classes and then convert to the BindingList<T>.  The Binding<T> will not work if the classes are defined wrong.